# rails migration. modify starting point for auto_increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have a table already created.  I am looking for a rails migration where I can modify the starting point of the `auto_increment` number for `id` column of my table.  Let's say I want it to start from `1000`.

I googled a bit and came across [this](http://dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations#create_table):

it says:

> :options  "string"    pass raw options to
>   your underlying database, e.g.
>   auto_increment = 10000. Note that
>   passing options will cause you to lose
>   the default ENGINE=InnoDB statement

Can this be used for something I want? and how will the migration look since i am changing the column and not creating new one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use raw [execute](http://dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations#execute) method

```
execute ("ALTER TABLE your_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000")
```